# Widget header unique classes

Tags: php, customization, widgets

I have created the code below for one of my widget sections.
Currently I am able to manipulate the title bar with  (h3.home-widget-header) which is good. But obviously it will be for all widgets in that section. There is 1 or two widgets that I need to style the positioning of the title bar slightly different. My question is - is this possible and how would I go about writing a unique class so I can manipulate each widget in that section individually.

Thanks ahead of time!

- Mike

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

```
register_sidebar(array(

    'name' => 'Homepage Widget Area',

    'before_widget' => '<li class="home-widget">',

    'after_widget' => '</li>',

    'before_title' => '<span class="home-widget-header"><h3 class="home-widget-header">',

    'after_title' => '</h3></span>',

));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please study the RELATED links here in the right sidebar.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

refer to this line:

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
```

`%1$s` outputs an id specific to the widget type; `%2$s` outputs a widget specific class including an unique number.